# How to remove the HUGE padding for tabs and icons in Eclipse on Linux Mint 17.3 Xfce edition?

Tags: eclipse, linux-mint, xfce

I've just installed Linux Mint 17.3 Xfce edition on a laptop and went on to install Eclipse Mars.2 after I have finished playing with colors everywhere.

I've downloaded the gzipped tarball and extracted it in my home, started it, and got this bad surprise:

[image: My almost brand new Eclipse]

I've already tried [this](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes/wiki/Linux-Huge-Toolbar-Problem) but as you can see on the screenshot, it didn't work

I've been searching and tinkering css files for now, in /usr/share/themes but haven't been successful (I'm not even sure which theme I'm using).